# How many teams can 10 people form?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

I've looked into some other relevant questions but I think mine is a bit more general. I'm trying to find the number of all the possible scenarios when splitting 10 people to groups of **any** number.

From what I remember from my probability courses, I can find the number of teams  when they are exactly 2. They can either be groups of 8/1 , 7/2 , 6/3 etc. For any of those I just have to find the combinations of 8 people ,7, 6 etc and add them all to get all the possible 2 team combinations of any number of members.

Now the same thing must be done for 3 team and then added to the number we found for 2 teams. Here's where I get confused. Then we go on for 4 teams , 5 teams all the way up to 10 teams of 1. Finally of course we add the numbers of all these cases .

Can I find the total number more easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking for the number of ways to divide $10$ people into groups, which is the same as the number of equivalence classes on a set of $10$ elements.  This is the [Bell number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number) $B_{10}$.

**EDIT** This is in response to the comment by mm8511.  I tried to make it a comment, but I couldn't type the formula correctly with seeing a preview.

There is a [triangle scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_triangle) for computing the Bell numbers.  There is also an exact formula in terms of a finite sum $$
B_n= \left\lceil\frac{1}{e}\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{k^n}{n!}\right\rceil$$
This formula is problem $51$ in "The Art of Mathematics" by Bela Bollobas, where it is attributed to L. Comtet.

Comment: Just as a note, the bell number is not (in general) easy to compute. No nice closed form is known, just asymptotics.

Comment: You are correct. I should have been more specific with what I meant by  "nice closed form." I was referring to the notion that is often used in combinatorics, where a closed from expression is one without recursively defined terms, sums, products, etc. Typically only "elementary functions" are allowed. This is obviously subjective though. Thanks for pointing that out.